# Android Pay integration in native app

Tags: android, google-play-services, payment, android-pay

I have integrated Android Pay in my native Android app. It gives me the error:

> There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant

Android Pay is not available in my country (India), but I have changed my region to US on my Google account and added an US card in my Android Pay app (Android Pay supportable card).

Also beta version of app is uploaded to test Android Pay on Google Play Store.

Still the same error.

Comment: You may want to see this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020432/android-pay-testing-from-outside-us?rq=1), "They said it checks your IP address to determine location" that's why you still received the same response. You may read the [Review requirements](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/get-started), as stated **"Please carefully review this list before you start development. If your business and your application can work with the following requirements and restrictions, you can go ahead with the integration process."**

Comment: @Mamta kaundal any success ?

Answer (score 0):

Double check you are using

WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST

I had the same error because I was using WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX which has now been deprecated

Comment: Yes it is WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST

Comment: @MamtaKaundal i'm trying the same but it does not work for testing environment

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Google. They gave me an instruction telling me to use WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX because it is not supported in my country even though it was deprecated. You also need to use some test cards they provided.