# Android Pay Error in "loadMaskedWallet"

Tags: android, android-pay

I am trying to make a test payment with Android Pay. So far I have configured my device for testing based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020432/android-pay-testing-from-outside-us), I have configured a card in Android app in my device and based on this code:

```
Wallet.Payments.isReadyToPay(mGoogleApiClient, IsReadyToPayRequest.newBuilder()
                   .addAllowedCardNetwork(WalletConstants.CardNetwork.VISA)
                   .addAllowedCardNetwork(WalletConstants.CardNetwork.MASTERCARD)
                   .build())
                .setResultCallback(
                        booleanResult -> {
                           if (booleanResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) { // says true
...
```

I have build my example based on these guidelines from [google code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-pay/index.html)

```
private void initGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(),0, this)
            .addApi(Wallet.API, new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
                    .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                    .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_LIGHT)
                    .build())
            .build();
}
```

and then:

```
    private void initAndroidPayView() {
    mWalletFragment = (SupportWalletFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(WALLET_FRAGMENT_ID);

    if (mWalletFragment == null) {
        // Wallet fragment style
        WalletFragmentStyle walletFragmentStyle = new WalletFragmentStyle()
                .setBuyButtonText(WalletFragmentStyle.BuyButtonText.BUY_WITH)
                .setBuyButtonWidth(WalletFragmentStyle.Dimension.MATCH_PARENT);

        // Wallet fragment options
        WalletFragmentOptions walletFragmentOptions = WalletFragmentOptions.newBuilder()
                .setEnvironment(WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                .setFragmentStyle(walletFragmentStyle)
                .setTheme(WalletConstants.THEME_DARK)
                .setMode(WalletFragmentMode.BUY_BUTTON)
                .build();

        // Initialize the WalletFragment
        WalletFragmentInitParams.Builder startParamsBuilder =
                WalletFragmentInitParams.newBuilder()
                        .setMaskedWalletRequest(generateMaskedWalletRequest())
                        .setMaskedWalletRequestCode(MASKED_WALLET_REQUEST_CODE);
        //.setAccountName("Google I/O Codelab");//https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/fragment/WalletFragmentInitParams.Builder
        mWalletFragment = SupportWalletFragment.newInstance(walletFragmentOptions);
        mWalletFragment.initialize(startParamsBuilder.build());

        // Add the WalletFragment to the UI
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.androidPayContainer, mWalletFragment, WALLET_FRAGMENT_ID)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

I am using the

> PaymentMethodTokenizationType.NETWORK_TOKEN

and I generated the publicKey as written in github repo

Now when I make the payment I get this error code in the onActivityResult: `10`

In the device I see only this error message:

> **Request Failed** An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later.

And when I press ok in the error dialog I get this log:

> 06-01 12:18:05.739 11386 11386 W WalletMerchantError: Error in
>   loadMaskedWallet: Did you forget the set Android Pay testing
>   environment to PROD?

I tried also changing the variables to Production but still the same error.
Does anyone have any solution or I really have to try that later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this issue posted on Github

> https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart/issues/31

and other contacts there is an anomaly with Sandbox mode and the test card don't work at least in Europe.

The answer from the issue contains also an alternative solution.

> **Issue**: test cards (even the one provided by Google) don't work anymore
> (at least not outside of US);
>
> **Solution**: you need real card to make it
> work. You won't be charged with ENVIRONMENT_TEST.

Comment: Hi, I'm adding Google pay in my application, after selecting card it gives me this error: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}
can you please help me?

Comment: Make sure to follow this https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart and if you have problems you can open an issue there

Comment: Thank you! After adding gateway version, I was able to initiate google pay. Again thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use `ENVIRONMENT_TEST`, make sure you've followed the steps outlined in [Setup Android Pay](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/setup). Specifically, make sure your AndroidManifest.xml contains the following bit:

```
<application
  ...
  <!-- Enables the Android Pay API -->
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
    android:value="true" />
</application>
```

If you feel your app is ready and are trying to use `ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION`, then there a few more steps [outlined here](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/deployment).

Comment: Yes I have done that, also just to make sure I tried the google example and I have opened this issue: https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart/issues/31