# Android pay sandbox - Your card couldn't be added

Tags: android, stripe-payments, sandbox, android-pay, stripe-connect

I am trying to implement android pay with stripe API but I couldn't create sandbox environment for android pay and getting error "**Your card couldn't be added**"

I followed steps mentioned in this answer but no luck.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39656094/1468406

Please help.

Comment: According to the documentation, ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX is deprecated. Are you trying to use Android Pay in a country where it hasn't launched yet?

Comment: Yes in india...

Comment: @pratikbhiyani I think you should be used TunnelBear(Change VPN) App to download Android Pay App in India. If you have done with Android Pay test environment then card should be added in android pay app. I think you have missed something there. Please check properly.

Comment: it is done. Thanks.